How to listen to touch events on Leaflet GeoJSON?
I am trying to drag an object (circleMarker) with my fingers over a Leaflet map. For some reason I haven't been able to do it through the more conventional way:
    circle.on(
        {
        'touchstart': function () 
            {
            "do something"
            }
        }

"touchstart", "touchmove", "touchup"... they don't trigger any event there.
So I found a way around transforming the circlemarker object in a geojson object and adding and enabling "draggable", in  the following way:
geojson.eachLayer((layer)=>
        {
        layer.draggable = new L.Draggable(layer._path);
    layer.draggable.enable()
         ...              
        })  

Now I am able to drag the object with my fingers but what I really need is to trigger an event when this happen, so I am trying:
geojson.eachLayer((layer)=>
        {
        layer.draggable = new L.Draggable(layer._path);
    layer.draggable.enable()
        layer.on('touchmove', function(event)
            {
            console.log('yeah!!!!');
            })
        }) 

and It isn't working.
It does trigger events if I replace 'touchmove' with 'mousemove' and use the mouse instead.
My entire script below:
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    gestureHandling: "none",
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ],
    center: [41.00, -104],
    zoom: 5
});

var lat = 41.00;

var lng = -104;

var radius = 25

var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: radius,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
}

var circle = L.circleMarker([lat, lng], radius, geojsonMarkerOptions)

var geojsonFeature = circle.toGeoJSON();

var circle = L.circleMarker([lat,lng], geojsonMarkerOptions)

var geojson = L.geoJSON([geojsonFeature], {

    pointToLayer : function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    },

    onEachFeature(feature,layer)
        {
            layer.on('touchstart', function(event) {
                console.log('marker is dragged'); })
        }
    
}).addTo(map);

geojson.eachLayer((layer)=>{
    layer.draggable = new L.Draggable(layer._path);
    layer.draggable.enable()
    layer.on('touchmove', function(event) {
        console.log('yeah!!!'); })
})

Could somebody help me please?. Thanks in advance
I didn't find any related question in Stackoverflow
